# Overflow text to left instead of to right

Tags: css, overflow, alignment

I am displaying an email address below a form field.  I need the address to left align with the form field.  However, when the address is very long, instead of flowing past the end of the form field, I want the address to overflow to the left, basically right aligning with the field.

A sample image can be provided.

Comment: if by "a sample image can be provided" you mean you can show us what you want it to look like, please do.

Comment: You totally need to add that image.

Comment: Here is a link to the image: http://www.myazbar.com/overFlowtoLeft.jpg

The green div is the column that everything must fit in. I want all addresses to start about 92px to the right... unless they would overflow the span/div for email.  Then I want the email to right align to the edge of green and overflow left as far as needed.

Because only one email address will ever be shown at a time, it will look fine.

Comment: @thirdydot Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
mySelector
{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This tells the element you selected to break words up when they hit the side of the element. Not sure on browser support though.

Comment: That works as a temporary solution but is not the look I was going for.  I'd rather not break the address into multiple lines.  Instead I would prefer to push it to the left.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the CSS [word-wrap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap).

*Word wrap* allows you to force long (unbroken) text to wrap onto a new line. It's commonly used to prevent long URLs from overflowing a narrow content area (such as a sidebar on a website or in blog comments).

For example, you can use it to prevent text extending outside of an area and possibly breaking a layout:

[image]

To use `word-wrap`, specify either `word-wrap: normal` or `word-wrap: break-word`.

```
.email-address {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**Normal** means the text will extend beyond the boundaries of it's parent.
**Break-word** means the text will wrap to next line.

For your situation, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NznuF/) with a basic example of how you might implement your idea.

[image]

To get the email address to be left-aligned or right-aligned depending on its length, you'll need to use a bit of JavaScript.

Nevertheless, word-wrap is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 1.0+, Safari 1.0+, Opera 10.5+.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Kyle's answer, if you put your email address text into a *block* element, give it a fixed width equal to that of the input element, and set `word-wrap:break-word;` it'll work. It's CSS3, but it works as far back as IE5.
HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<span class="email">
  thisisareallylongemailthatwillprobablyoverflow@myreallylonginternetserviceprovider.superlongandimpossibletopleveldomain
</span>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    width:150px;   
}
span.email {
    width:150px;
      word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/2eDAG/3/)

Comment: You forgot `word-wrap: break-word` :)

Comment: @thirtydot WHOOPS hahaha i was using Chrome Dev Tools and forgot to update the actual fiddle, lol.